# в чём ошибка и как её исправить?

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk
def click():
     a = float(entry1.get())
     b = float(entry2.get())
     c = (2*a)+(2*b)
     label3['text'] = str (c)
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x250") 
label1 = tk. Label(window, text = "основа")
label1.pack() 
entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
entry1.pack() 
label2 = tk. Label(window, text = "бічна сторона")
label2.pack() 
entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
entry2.pack() 
label3 = tk. Label (window, text = "периметр")
label3.pack() 
button1 = tk.Button(window, text = " (2*a)+(2*b) ",  command=click)
button1.pack() 
window.mainloop()
```

Выдаёт ошибку в 3 строке как недопустимый символ.

[image]

Comment: Приведите более подробное объяснение ошибки **прямо в вопросе** (вопрос можно править, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1502323/edit)).

Comment: а у меня вот работает

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас что-то не так с отступом. Попробуйте просто ввести отступ заново.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что у вас в функции вместо 4 пробелов - 5.